# Save asynchronous retrofit response

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2

I am using `retrofit:2.1.0` and I am trying to save the response returned to my own POJO (UserProfile) but I can't seem to access the POJO, I assign the response to, outside of the callbacks.

So, in this call below, I want to have access to **UserProfile** outside of this call.

```
//adding `UserProfile userProfile;` outside of Call didn't help either

call.enqueue(new Callback<UserProfile>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<UserProfile> call, Response<UserProfile> response) {
       if (response.isSuccessful()) {
          UserProfile userProfile = response.body();
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<UserProfile> call, Throwable t) {
         //do something
    }
});
```

//here userProfile is null and hence can't get status
Log.d(TAG, "Status outside of Call is: " + userProfile.getStatus());

**New approach, same result**

```
private List<UserProfile> userProfileList = new ArrayList<>();

call.enqueue(new Callback<UserProfile>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<UserProfile> call, Response<UserProfile> response) {
       if (response.isSuccessful()) {
          UserProfile userProfile = response.body();
          userProfileList.add(userProfile);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<UserProfile> call, Throwable t) {
         //do something
    }
});
```

**And this one gets fired even before callback and hence is null**

```
if(userProfileList.size() > 0) {
     for(UserProfile userProfile : userProfileList) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Status is: " + userProfile.getStatus());
     }
} else {
     Log.d(TAG, "YakkerProfileList is NULL");
}
```

Comment: "I can't seem to access the POJO, I assign the response to, outside of the callbacks." - what exactly you want to do? Do you get any error?

Comment: *When* are you trying to access the `UserProfile`? If you try to access it before the callback is fired, it will return `null`.

Comment: Yes, outside of the `call` I can't even access `UserProfile`. I tried creating an instance of  `UserProfile` and then access `userProfile = response.body()` and when I do a getter like so: `Log.d(TAG, "User status outside of Call is: " + userProfile.getStatus());`

Comment: You should place UserProfile at the top of your class, and then assign it to a value inside of the call, after getting your response.

Comment: @Bryan yes, I am accessing UserProfile outside of Call but I am not sure when the call gets fired and when I should access the value.

Comment: @HtmlTosin see the updated code, even then I can't.  Also, if I declare `UserProfile` outside, I have to declare it final and hence can't assign a new value within `onResponse()`

Comment: @HtmlTosin see my updated implementation. It doesn't seem to matter where UserProfile or UserProfileList is declared, since the callback gets fired much later than where my logs are placed. There's got to be a way to handle asynchronous callback responses.

Comment: You are suppose to pass your callback response to a method after response.isSuccessful(), and allow your method to do whatever you want it to do. I see no reason why you are doing it outside of the Call itself.  "If you try to access it before the callback is fired, it will return null " -- You have already been told !

Comment: Yes, I am now calling a setter in `onResponse()` and that enabled me to use the response anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I added a setter in `onResponse()` which allowed me to use the response object elsewhere in the code like so:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<UserProfile> call, Response<UserProfile> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        UserProfile userProfile = response.body();
        //elsewhere in the code, I can read the value from this method
        setUserProfile(userProfile.getStatus());
    }
 }
```